# How do I interactively access Linux sub-directories through a perl script?

Tags: linux, perl

Here is my sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

print "Enter the name of the input file and its relevant path:\n";
my $file1 = <STDIN>;
chomp $file1;

open (DOC,"$file1") || die "Could not open $file1, $!";
```

Is there a better way to interactively specify a file-name, along with its path?

A way by which, similar to a Linux command line interface, a user can :

- Use <kbd>tab</kbd>, to auto-complete the path?
- View the content of the current directory, by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the perl module [Term::Complete](http://perldoc.perl.org/Term/Complete.html) to allow the user auto-completing the path.
Term::Complete requires an array with the words which shall be auto-completed so you would need to read the content of the current directory and save it to an array.
Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Term::Complete;
use File::Find qw(finddepth);

finddepth(sub {
        return if ($_ eq '.' || $_ eq '..');
        push @files, $File::Find::name;
}, '/');
$input = Complete('File: ', \@files);
```

Comment: Thats true, i've added a new example.